# How to maintain session in android webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I am using webview to display my website. When user click any links that is opened in a new tab or a new window user loosing his login session. But in any other browser it works fine. How to overcame the problem of login session null.

I'm using shouldOverrideUrlLoading to open links in new tab

Comment: Post your actual code.  You mention tabs-  webview doesn't do tabs.  Do you mean that you're opening it in a new WebView?  That would be a new session, because it's a different webview entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to open new window with same login session? My website has many links thats opens in new tab and new window.  So user is loosing the login session again and again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no such thing as a new window with a webview.  It doesn't have windows or tabs.  It's an Android view.  You're think it's a full fledged browser, it isn't.  Did you maybe mean you're using Chrome not WebView?